# How to filter specific items from a list after calling an API using Retrofit?

Tags: android, rest, kotlin, retrofit

I am calling an API of cricapi.com and display it using Retrofit. It displays a list of current matches. I want to only display the Indian Premier League matches from the api result.

This is the API result. Here i want display the 4th and 5th items as they are IPL ones. How can i display these two only. These two have same match IDs so can i filter by the IDs. The API doesn't have filter option

```
{
  "apikey": "*************************************",
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "853f13a8-f66f-4c06-87a9-72fa250ad9b5",
      "name": "Cambodia vs Singapore, 5th Match, Group B",
      "matchType": "t20",
      "status": "Innings Break",
      "venue": "AZ Group Cricket Oval, Phnom Penh",
      "date": "2023-05-04",
      "dateTimeGMT": "2023-05-04T03:30:00",
      "teams": [
        "Cambodia",
        "Singapore"
      ],
      "teamInfo": [
        {
          "name": "Singapore",
          "shortname": "SGP",
          "img": "https://g.cricapi.com/iapi/576-637877085561587712.webp?w=48"
        }
      ],
      "score": [
        {
          "r": 181,
          "w": 7,
          "o": 20,
          "inning": "Cambodia Inning 1"
        }
      ],
      "series_id": "4e815aab-596e-4507-92ea-8bec93f9c2c1",
      "fantasyEnabled": true,
      "bbbEnabled": false,
      "hasSquad": true,
      "matchStarted": true,
      "matchEnded": false
    },
    {
      "id": "a5cf1727-5472-4ef7-8cdb-3ffea5502c83",
      "name": "Malaysia vs Thailand, 4th Match, Group A",
      "matchType": "t20",
      "status": "Malaysia won by 8 wkts",
      "venue": "AZ Group Cricket Oval, Phnom Penh",
      "date": "2023-05-04",
      "dateTimeGMT": "2023-05-04T00:00:00",
      "teams": [
        "Malaysia",
        "Thailand"
      ],
      "teamInfo": [
        {
          "name": "Malaysia",
          "shortname": "MAL",
          "img": "https://g.cricapi.com/iapi/625-637865062320348912.webp?w=48"
        },
        {
          "name": "Thailand",
          "shortname": "THAI",
          "img": "https://g.cricapi.com/iapi/661-637873698140793668.webp?w=48"
        }
      ],
      "score": [
        {
          "r": 113,
          "w": 8,
          "o": 20,
          "inning": "Thailand Inning 1"
        },
        {
          "r": 114,
          "w": 2,
          "o": 12.3,
          "inning": "Malaysia Inning 1"
        }
      ],
      "series_id": "4e815aab-596e-4507-92ea-8bec93f9c2c1",
      "fantasyEnabled": true,
      "bbbEnabled": false,
      "hasSquad": true,
      "matchStarted": true,
      "matchEnded": true
    },
    {
      "id": "b95dc53a-4d46-439e-889c-953782e74ac4",
      "name": "Philippines vs Singapore, 3rd Match, Group B",
      "matchType": "t20",
      "status": "Singapore won by 87 runs",
      "venue": "AZ Group Cricket Oval, Phnom Penh",
      "date": "2023-05-03",
      "dateTimeGMT": "2023-05-03T07:30:00",
      "teams": [
        "Philippines",
        "Singapore"
      ],
      "teamInfo": [
        {
          "name": "Philippines",
          "shortname": "PHL",
          "img": "https://g.cricapi.com/iapi/70-637869112270788027.webp?w=48"
        },
        {
          "name": "Singapore",
          "shortname": "SGP",
          "img": "https://g.cricapi.com/iapi/576-637877085561587712.webp?w=48"
        }
      ],
      "score": [
        {
          "r": 181,
          "w": 5,
          "o": 20,
          "inning": "Singapore Inning 1"
        },
        {
          "r": 94,
          "w": 9,
          "o": 20,
          "inning": "Philippines Inning 1"
        }
      ],
      "series_id": "4e815aab-596e-4507-92ea-8bec93f9c2c1",
      "fantasyEnabled": true,
      "bbbEnabled": false,
      "hasSquad": true,
      "matchStarted": true,
      "matchEnded": true
    },
    {
      "id": "08629a55-7d6e-4b82-8157-10c1d1eb4d02",
      "name": "Lucknow Super Giants vs Chennai Super Kings, 45th Match",
      "matchType": "t20",
      "status": "No result",
      "venue": "Bharat Ratna Shri Atal Bihari Vajpayee Ekana Cricket Stadium, Lucknow",
      "date": "2023-05-03",
      "dateTimeGMT": "2023-05-03T10:00:00",
      "teams": [
        "Lucknow Super Giants",
        "Chennai Super Kings"
      ],
      "teamInfo": [
        {
          "name": "Chennai Super Kings",
          "shortname": "CSK",
          "img": "https://g.cricapi.com/iapi/135-637852956181378533.png?w=48"
        },
        {
          "name": "Lucknow Super Giants",
          "shortname": "LSG",
          "img": "https://g.cricapi.com/iapi/215-637876059669009476.png?w=48"
        }
      ],
      "score": [
        {
          "r": 125,
          "w": 7,
          "o": 19.2,
          "inning": "Lucknow Super Giants Inning 1"
        }
      ],
      "series_id": "c75f8952-74d4-416f-b7b4-7da4b4e3ae6e",
      "fantasyEnabled": true,
      "bbbEnabled": true,
      "hasSquad": true,
      "matchStarted": true,
      "matchEnded": true
    },
    {
      "id": "2f9ce8ba-4c85-4e90-8140-d632037d35db",
      "name": "Punjab Kings vs Mumbai Indians, 46th Match",
      "matchType": "t20",
      "status": "Mumbai Indians won by 6 wkts",
      "venue": "Punjab Cricket Association IS Bindra Stadium, Mohali",
      "date": "2023-05-03",
      "dateTimeGMT": "2023-05-03T14:00:00",
      "teams": [
        "Punjab Kings",
        "Mumbai Indians"
      ],
      "teamInfo": [
        {
          "name": "Mumbai Indians",
          "shortname": "MI",
          "img": "https://g.cricapi.com/iapi/226-637852956375593901.png?w=48"
        },
        {
          "name": "Punjab Kings",
          "shortname": "PBKS",
          "img": "https://g.cricapi.com/iapi/247-637852956959778791.png?w=48"
        }
      ],
      "score": [
        {
          "r": 214,
          "w": 3,
          "o": 20,
          "inning": "Punjab Kings Inning 1"
        },
        {
          "r": 216,
          "w": 4,
          "o": 18.5,
          "inning": "Mumbai Indians Inning 1"
        }
      ],
      "series_id": "c75f8952-74d4-416f-b7b4-7da4b4e3ae6e",
      "fantasyEnabled": true,
      "bbbEnabled": true,
      "hasSquad": true,
      "matchStarted": true,
      "matchEnded": true
    },
    {
      "id": "a3818181-5f03-4d26-b281-dfe63df938dc",
      "name": "Pakistan vs New Zealand, 3rd ODI",
      "matchType": "odi",
      "status": "Pakistan won by 26 runs",
      "venue": "National Stadium, Karachi",
      "date": "2023-05-01",
      "dateTimeGMT": "2023-05-01T09:30:00",
      "teams": [
        "Pakistan",
        "New Zealand"
      ],
      "teamInfo": [
        {
          "name": "New Zealand",
          "shortname": "NZ",
          "img": "https://g.cricapi.com/iapi/57-637877076980737903.webp?w=48"
        },
        {
          "name": "Pakistan",
          "shortname": "PAK",
          "img": "https://g.cricapi.com/iapi/66-637877075103236690.webp?w=48"
        }
      ],
      "score": [
        {
          "r": 287,
          "w": 6,
          "o": 50,
          "inning": "Pakistan Inning 1"
        },
        {
          "r": 261,
          "w": 10,
          "o": 49.1,
          "inning": "New Zealand Inning 1"
        }
      ],
      "series_id": "c059609d-19c0-4c11-9639-082a8db9f914",
      "fantasyEnabled": true,
      "bbbEnabled": true,
      "hasSquad": true,
      "matchStarted": true,
      "matchEnded": true
    }
  ],
  "status": "success",
  "info": {
    "hitsToday": 7,
    "hitsUsed": 1,
    "hitsLimit": 100,
    "credits": 0,
    "server": 18,
    "offsetRows": 0,
    "totalRows": 6,
    "queryTime": 17.258,
    "s": 0,
    "cache": 1
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you confirm that  if "series_id": "c75f8952-74d4-416f-b7b4-7da4b4e3ae6e" that you are getting , will it be always same for IPL matches

Comment: if it same, then you can filter object based on this id then move those objects to top position in entire list.

Comment: @KishanMaurya There is no information about that in the documentations. Maybe i have to use API for few days to see it's same

Comment: Or may be you can filter based on team names. Since in IPL ,we know here are only 10 team , You can use ENUMS of them 

."teams": [
        "Punjab Kings",
        "Mumbai Indians"
      ]

Comment: @KishanMaurya I'll try with series id as it would be easier. If it didn't work then i'll go this way

Answer (score 0):

You just need to filter the response by ID of the league.

```
interface MatchesApi {
    @GET("request_path")
    suspend fun getMatches() : List<Match>
}
```

In the place where you're getting the metches:

```
launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    val indianMatches = matchesApi.getMatches().filter { it.leagueId == INDINAN_LEAGUE_ID }
    .... // Do something with these matches
}
```